# How do I execute a module's code from another?

Tags: python

I know it's a greenhorn question. But. I have a very simple module that contains a class, and I want to call the module to run from another. Like so:

```
#module a, to be imported

import statements

if __name__ == '__main__':

    class a1:
        def __init__(self, stuff):
            do stuff

        def run_proc():
            do stuff involving 'a1' when called from another module

#Module that I'll run, that imports and uses 'a':
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import a

    a.run_proc()
```

However, for reasons that are likely obvious to others, I get the error Attribute Error: 'Module' object has no attribute 'run_proc' Do I need a static method for this class, or to have my run_proc() method within a class, that I initialize an instance of?

Comment: Do you know how classes work in python?

Comment: **Why** for the love of god is there a class definition within the main sentinel?

Comment: Don't define the class in the main.

Comment: Also, do you actually know what `if __name__ == '__main__':` does?

Comment: @The-IT I'm thinking it keeps a module from executing on import. Am I wrong? And if I am, maybe you have some sort of intelligent feedback?

Comment: I didn't mean to come off as provocative, and I'm sorry if I did. I thought you may have had a reason for doing what you did in the code and I was trying to pinpoint what it was so I could potentially help you better. If you where just say copying someone else code and using it as like a template but didn't actually know what classes and the `__name__` was, then I could have told you a way to do what you where trying to do with out those, just like Steve Barnes did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

in module a to the end of the file and add pass or some test code.

Your problems are that:

1. Any thing in the scope of `if __name__ == '__main__':` is only considered in the top level file.
2. You are defining a class but not creating a class instance.

## module a, to be imported

```
import statements

class a1:
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        do stuff

    def run_proc():
        #do stuff involving 'a1' when called from another module


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass # Replace with test code!
```

## Module that I'll run, that imports and uses 'a':

```
import a
def do_a():
    A = a.a1()   # Create an instance
    A.run_proc() # Use it

if __name__ == '__main__':
   do_a()
```

Comment: Just as I had suspected. Thanks for the constructive help.